# submitting form using remote: true in rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This is my view

```
<%= form_tag url_for(action: :comt, id: @com.id), remote: true do |f| %>
<textarea name="inst">test</textarea>
<button class="small"  id="btn">Submit</button>
```

Here is my controller:

```
def comt
    id= params[:id]
    @com = comment.find id
    if @com.update_attribute(:instruction, params[:inst])
      redirect_to action: :index
    end
  end
```

It is working correctly but i need it using ajax.
If i remove redirect_to it throwing error message. Where i am wrong. Can anyone correct it.

Comment: Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.12

Comment: You have the jQuery stuff loaded?